# Show custom view when local notifications is fired

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I want to show custom view for local notifications with YES and NO button actions. How can I achieve it?

Here is the view I want to show.

[image]

Comment: You can use `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)` this function to fire a delegate in your class to show the alert.

Comment: You can write a method to show the alert in your common class with a parameter that will decide in which controller you want to show your alert, and then from the above mentioned method you can call the method in your common class to show the alert on your viewcontroller.

Comment: and for your YES and NO button, you don't need to create a custom view, you can use `UIAlertController` provided by Apple.